# Delphi Component installation error

Tags: delphi

I tried to install a component in Delphi XE7, which includes 5 DPKs, but unfortunately I didn't succeed. I get this error message:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] XXX1.dpk(1): E2225 Never-build package 'XXX1' must be recompiled
>   [dcc32 Fatal Error] XXX2.dpk(34): E2202 Required package 'XXX1' not found

When I compiled XXX1 alone, it works fine !

I don't know how to build all 5 DPKs without any error.

[*Edit*:] Based on [Remy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37954104/512728), I changed the last line in the fist dbk from `{$IMPLICITBUILD OFF}` to `{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}` like below, but still the same error, what's the issue now?

```
{$R *.res}  
{$IFDEF IMPLICITBUILDING This IFDEF should not be used by users}  
{$ALIGN 8}  
{$ASSERTIONS ON}  
{$BOOLEVAL OFF}  
{$DEBUGINFO ON}  
{$EXTENDEDSYNTAX ON}  
{$IMPORTEDDATA ON}  
{$IOCHECKS ON}  
{$LOCALSYMBOLS ON}  
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}  
{$OPENSTRINGS ON}  
{$OPTIMIZATION OFF}  
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}  
{$RANGECHECKS OFF}  
{$REFERENCEINFO ON}  
{$SAFEDIVIDE OFF}  
{$STACKFRAMES ON}  
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}  
{$VARSTRINGCHECKS ON}  
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}  
{$MINENUMSIZE 1}  
{$IMAGEBASE $400000}  
{$DEFINE DEBUG}  
{$ENDIF IMPLICITBUILDING}  
{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}
```

Comment: What component(s)/packages were you trying to install?  I can't see how you'll get much help without readers knowing that.

Comment: @MartynA: I suspect it is Indy, which has 5 DPKs, and does disable implicit compiling. This error is not unheard of.

Answer (score 1):

The second error is just a side effect of the first error.

The first error is because the DPK needs to be re-compiled, probably because no DCUs can be found for it, but it has an [`{$IMPLICITBUILD OFF}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Implicit_Build_(Delphi)) directive to prevent implicit re-compiling.  When you manually re-compile the DPK explicitly, it works.  Then the second error should go away, as long as the second DPK can find the compiled DCUs for the first DPK.